# kibana 4.5 how to get access dashboard

Tags: kibana-4

I read http://blog.trifork.com/2014/05/20/advanced-kibana-dashboard/
blog,there the author explain how to create dashboard from json file or from script, and access by next url:

http://localhost/kibana/#/dashboard/file/logstash.json

and this

http://localhost/kibana/#/dashboard/script/logstash.js

but it's only in kibana 3

How you can do it in kibana 4.5?

I tried 
http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/file/export.json
but kibana direct me to discover page, and give me
"Could not locate that dashboard (id: export.json)"
error

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kibana documentation shows the url structure for Kibana.

Please look into dashboard sharing section

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/dashboard.html#sharing-dashboards

example link

`http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard`

Comment: thanks but I don't want iframe share link , because its close ,I want script that I can decide which dashboard or visualize to load in run time

Comment: Check the second link in docs, it allows you to decide which dashboard to load

Comment: Can you copy the link?, I can not fint it

Comment: I have shared the documentation link

Answer (score 0):

try http://localhost:5601/ & go to dashboard tab to access dashboard.